# Why is it that the equation of a massless scalar field *must* be conformal invariant?

Tags: differential-geometry, mass, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

I'm reading a paper [1], p.111 where it is said that:

> However, the equation of scalar field with zero mass must be conformal
>   invariant while equation $\square\varphi=0$ does not satisfy this
>   requirement by any means. The conformal invariant equation is:
>   $$\square \varphi + \frac{n-2}{4(n-1)}R\varphi = 0 $$
>   where $R$ is the
>   scalar curvature of space-time and $n$ is its dimensionality.

Question: why is it that the equation of a massless scalar field *must* be conformal invariant?

This question is related to this other question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/270088/

---

- [1] : *Quantum theory of scalar field in de Sitter space-time*, N. A. Chernikov and E. A. Tagirov, 1968

Comment: I would say that this perhaps not much more than a way to define the word "massless" in curved space. But I am curious if anyone else has an independent definition.